# what are /sys/kernel/debug/dri number means?

Tags: centos, kernel

under `/sys/kernel/debug/dri` there are couple folders in there, what are those numbers represent? are they bus numbers? PCI numbers?

is it possible to map that information with lshw or even lspci?

ps. I'm using CentOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They map to [device minors](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_debugfs.c#n77); you can see the correspondence with the numbers in `/dev/dri/`:

```
$ sudo ls /sys/kernel/debug/dri
0  128  64

$ ls -l /dev/dri/
total 0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 226,   0 Sep 19 23:28 card0
crw-rw----  1 root video 226,  64 Aug 30 18:44 controlD64
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 226, 128 Aug 30 18:44 renderD128
```

The `name` file in each directory will tell you which driver and device these map to:

```
i915 dev=0000:00:02.0 master=pci:0000:00:02.0 unique=0000:00:02.0
```